# Surface area of projected triangle

Tags: 3d, geometry

How could I got about calculating the surface area of a triangle as it is projected onto the screen. Given projection, view, model matrices and the 3 vertex positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Project the vertices onto the screen with the model-view and projection matrices from your rendering pipeline
2. Calculate the surface area in 2D with `A = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))` with `s = (a+b+c)/2` and `a`, `b`, `c`, the lengths of the three sides of the triangle using some 2D vector math (this is [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula))

Comment: by the way, do be careful to use the right model-view matrix, this one is constantly changing while your rendering your scene due to the rotate/translate calls etc that you make. You need to do your calculation at the point you render the triangle or save the model-view matrix used at that time for reuse when you're calculating this area.

Comment: I'm doing this in a shader, so the matrices I'm sending are the ones used for rendering